# My loop from mysql_fetch_array() does not output any answers. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

Here is the following code that I have running. The database.php contains a function called fetch_array(). fetch_array() contains mysql_fetch_array() within its function and returns the result of mysql_fetch_array(). Database.php contains a database class with other functions within it.Is there any reason why this code might not work? I would like to get the id's and usernames of each record in the table users.

```
 <?php
  require_once("database.php");
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

    global $database;
    echo "hello";
    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    while($row = fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "ID: $row[id] Name: $row[username] <br />";
    }

 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: function is wrong, it shoul be mysql_fetch_array

Comment: The function is mysql_fetch_array. It is called fetch_array because i made that the name of the function in database.php

Comment: @tdelaney18, after you comment I'm downvoting!

Comment: @Adnan LOL and am upvoting your comment

Comment: remove semi-colon at the end of your query string

Comment: I don't understand why you would down vote on a comment. I am just trying to help the question become more clear.

Comment: @tdelaney18 he's probably down voting because what you are doing is considered as "BAD PRACTICE" in PHP

Comment: No, downvote was irrelevant to your code. It was because your question isn't clear, we have no idea what's `$database` or `fetch_array()` or what's even inside `database.php`. You can't assume that people are mind readers.

Answer (score 2):

You're retrieving only `id`, not `username`. Thus, you won't get `username` output when fetching.

Replace:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT id FROM users;");
```

With:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT id, username FROM users;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT query is wrong. You are currently only returning the 'id' column of each row you are selecting. This when you try to echo $row[username] you will most likely get a warning of non-existent array key.

To fix the issue change this line:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT id FROM users;");
```

to

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT id, username FROM users;");
```

Or if you want to get all columns with each row:

```
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users;");
```

For more information see the [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) reference in the MySQL documentation.